# Django is trying to duplicate rows

Tags: python, mysql, django

i'm trying to make initial migration (for making some default tables) and it breaks on:

```
[...]
b"SELECT `django_content_type`.`id`, `django_content_type`.`name`,`django_content_type`.`app_label`, `django_content_type`.`model` FROM `django_content_type` WHERE (`django_content_type`.`model` = 'logentry' AND `django_content_type`.`app_label` = 'admin') LIMIT 21"
b'SET @@session.autocommit = OFF'
b"INSERT INTO `django_content_type` (`name`, `app_label`, `model`) VALUES ('log entry', 'admin', 'logentry')"
b'COMMIT'
b'SET @@session.autocommit = ON'
b'SELECT `auth_permission`.`content_type_id`, `auth_permission`.`codename` FROM `auth_permission` INNER JOIN `django_content_type` ON ( `auth_permission`.`content_type_id` = `django_content_type`.`id` ) WHERE `auth_permission`.`content_type_id` IN (1) ORDER BY `django_content_type`.`app_label` ASC, `django_content_type`.`model` ASC, `auth_permission`.`codename` ASC'
b'SET @@session.autocommit = OFF'
b"INSERT INTO `auth_permission` (`name`, `content_type_id`, `codename`) VALUES ('Can add log entry', 1, 'add_logentry'), ('Can change log entry', 1, 'change_logentry'), ('Can delete log entry', 1, 'delete_logentry')"
b'COMMIT'
b'SET @@session.autocommit = ON'
b"SELECT `django_content_type`.`id`, `django_content_type`.`name`, `django_content_type`.`app_label`, `django_content_type`.`model` FROM `django_content_type` WHERE `django_content_type`.`app_label` = 'admin' ORDER BY `django_content_type`.`name` ASC"
b'SET @@session.autocommit = OFF'
b"INSERT INTO `django_content_type` (`name`, `app_label`, `model`) VALUES ('log entry', 'admin', 'logentry')"
b'ROLLBACK'
b'SET @@session.autocommit = ON'
```

and i have got an exception:

```
[...]
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Duplicate entry 'admin-logentry' for key 'django_content_type_app_label_3ec8c61c_uniq'
[...]
```

it is trying to add the same row twice, but why?

installed apps from my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

and db:

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
    'NAME': '###',
    'HOST': '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',
    'USER': '###',
    'PASSWORD': '###'
},
```

django version 1.7 and python 3.2

(i printed sqls by modifying file /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py)

EDIT:

ok, I fixed that by changing my schema collation to "utf8 - default collation". problably some django module or connector was not able to compare select results and was trying to insert the same.

Answer (score 0):

The name is the primary key, and you insert

```
"INSERT INTO `django_content_type` (`name`, `app_label`, `model`) VALUES ('log entry', 'admin', 'logentry')"
 INSERT INTO `django_content_type` (`name`, `app_label`, `model`) VALUES ('log entry', 'admin', 'logentry')" b'COMMIT'
```

the primary key is the same value.

Comment: i know that, but this code is generated by django. i only started new project, configured db connection and made migration. so how can I fix that?